# What is a good/polite expression for the word "ma'am"?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

Doing some translation work for a comic and I'm trying to come up with a good alternative for ma'am. The specific context of the scene is a cop arriving at a crime scene and asking a woman, "Ma'am, are you okay?"

To my understanding, Japanese doesn't really have any direct equivalents to Ma'am/Sir, so I'm unsure what word/expression to use, especially in this context of what a police officer would use to address a civilian of similar age while also maintaining politeness and police professionalism. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a story set in modern Japan and the cop does not have some peculiar personality, it's best to ignore "ma'am" and just say 大丈夫ですか. If you really need a word to draw her attention before it, it would be あのー ("hello") or すみません ("excuse me").

ご婦人 might be used if the story is set in the Taisho period (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26079/5010)), but this is virtually obsolete in modern Japanese. お嬢さん might be another option when the woman is relatively young, but it's not common anymore, either.